# Laravel 7: Task schedule command if column has date and matched with current date

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-queue

I want to create task schedule command. My critieria is:
I have a customer table where customers have `due_date` column. So if this column is not null and has date, the date will match current date and send sms to customer mobile number.

scheduleSms Command File:

```
protected $signature = 'send:scheduleSms';
 public function handle()
    {
        $customer = Customer::where('due_date', '!=', null)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        $today = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');

        foreach($customer as $row){
            if($row->due_date == $today){
            $id = 1;
            $sms_settings = SmsSetting::findOrFail($id);
            if($sms_settings->schedule_active == 1){
                $name = $row->name;
                $date = $row->due_date;
                $total_due = number_format($row->due);
                $msgs =  $sms_settings->schedule_sms;
                $find = ['#name#','#date#', '#total_due#',];
                $replacement = [$name, $date, $total_due  ];
                $msg = str_replace( $find, $replacement, $msgs);
                $send= SMS::shoot($row->mobile, $msg);
            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\scheduleSms'
    ];
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('send:scheduleSms')
        ->everyMinute()
        ->runInBackground()
        ->timezone('Asia/Dhaka');
    }
```

Suppose Today I scheduled a customer due_date to 2022-08-20, then `$send= SMS::shoot($customer->mobile, $msg);` this will execute only once for each customer at 2022-08-20. Also If I have many customers due date, it sends all sms at once which may crush for huge amounts.

Can you please modify the code, so that it takes 2/3second time gap between each sms and send only one sms each customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's useful

Make a command first

```
php artisan make:command SendSMS
```

You define code in `handle()` function and

`$signature = 'sms:send';` (This is example , you can change if you want to be)

In `Kernel.php`

`$schedule->command('sms:send')->daily()->runInBackground();`

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please recheck?

Comment: I think you should use daily() or dailyAt() (maybe dailyAt(7:00)) instead of everyMinute() . It't just send one message to specified customer

Comment: If you use everyMinute() , this cron will run every minute

Comment: how can I set some time interval for each sms?

Comment: And can you please check, my code is correct or not for sending sms?

Comment: Yah , your code is correct